# How do I disable Ktorrent from autostarting on login?

Tags: login, autostart, ktorrent

I'm using Kbuntu and when I turn on my computer and log in, the default app KTorrent automatically starts up and opens a window on my desktop. I want KTorrent to open up when I manually select the application from the start menu. I check in the Ktorrent settings and I don't see an option, nor in the Autostart application, which is empty.

How do I stop KTorrent from automatically starting short of uninstalling the app?

Comment: I don't use kbuntu but run this `sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i ktorrent` and lets see if it's there it should be. If there disable with `sudo systemctl disable ktorrent`, now it won't start at boot

Comment: Open *System Settings* > *Startup & Shutdown* > *Desktop Session* and try *Start with an empty session* in the *On Login* section. Log out and log back in.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen thank you very much, that works!

Comment: @smeterlink let me post an answer so you can accept it!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I just disabled session restore. For some reasons I close ktorrent before shutting down but keeps opening it again if session restore is enabled.

Comment: @smeterlink that I believe is the normal behaviour for session restore on kubuntu

Answer (score 12):

When you close ktorrent, it's still running in the system tray.
If you have "restore previous session" enabled in the System "Startup and Shutdown" settings, KTorrent will be re-started in windowed mode, even if it was minimized to the tray when shut down.
[image: ktorrent still running in the system tray]
[image: System Settings - Restore Previous Session]
To prevent KTorrent from starting, either

1. close it by right clicking on it's tray entry and press "Quit".
   [image: closing ktorrent from system tray]
2. disabling "restore previous session" in System Settings

Answer (score 1):

Do two things:

1. First check to see if it's enabled with the command

   ```
   sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i ktorrent
   ```
2. Then disable it with

   ```
   sudo systemctl disable ktorrent
   ```

Info:

> list-unit-files [PATTERN...]
>              List unit files installed on the system, in combination with their enablement state (as reported by
>              is-enabled). If one or more PATTERNs are specified, only unit files whose name matches one of them are shown
>              (patterns matching unit file system paths are not supported).

Comment: I have ktorrent installed but does not appear when I run the command `sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i ktorrent`, maybe it's a ktorrent bug.

Comment: I can't find anything with `sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i ktorrent`

Comment: check for the binaries with `which ktorrent` assuming that's what it's called!

Comment: This doesn't make sense for this scenario. KTorrent is not, and does not, install a systemd service.